# ms Chart Multiple Series X Value Mismatch (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, charts, mschart, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm currently developing a website that shows multiple charts that I build using data from SQL tables. I've used and followed Scott Mitchell's tutorial (https://web.archive.org/web/20210927195532/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/093009-1.aspx) and K. Scott Allen's ChartBuilder class (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200903XASP/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2245) and all works well.

However when have two series that I want to show on the same Chart, if one set of data does not have all of the X values the other series does, the chart blindly puts all the data on, ignoring trying to match the X values of the other series, therefore mismatching the X values when the chart is shown.

I know that I can fiddle the data so that both sets of data have the same X values, however I'm trying to make the class handle anomalies in the data so that I don't have to worry too much about the data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

chart.DataBindCrossTab match it for you. 
See more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx